# How to connect two meshes seamlessly?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

So I am sculpting a head, while following a tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmmSAsn_mOk. I created eyelids and applied modifiers on them (subsurf and solidify). Now it´s time to merge the eyelids with the head and sculpt on them to make them seamlessly connect to the head. In order to do so I used (im sculpt mode) shift+r and than ctrl+r, like in the video right at 2.32 min. But than this happens (to the lower lid). [image: head]

Maybe I missed something done in the tutorial to connect the eyelids to the head. I didn´t succeed in doing so. Can someone help me out?
the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/iyg6tn0s4uclycm/head8.blend?dl=0

Comment: please share the file as it is just before the remesh. So if I apply the modifiers of the eyelids, join them to the body, then remesh, it works fine, maybe make sure that the remesh size is small enough?

Comment: I did just that and it works. But I used eyelids that weren´t subsurfed much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just as a side info**

> First of all you're running into an issue where you can't apply
> modifiers because of multi-user data.
>
> [image: Modifiers cannot be applied to multi-user data]
>
> This happens because your mesh is a linked data duplicate! In the
> Outliner you can see "Sphere" and "Sphere.018" both has "Sphere.002"
> and Sphere.002 is the linked data mesh. (this happens e.g. when you
> duplicate an object with alt+D)
>
> to make it a single object again you can delet either one of the
> objects (sphere or sphere.018) or you can click on the "2" in the
> "Object Data properties" marked with the arrow.
>
> [image]

My solution would be to do the eyelids from scratch.

First you **select your eyeball** and do **Cursor to Selected** (Shift+S)

Then you **add** a **Sphere** and **delete the half** of it and **add** a **Solidify modifier** and sacle to the eye.

[image]

Then you go into **right ortho view** with numpad 3. and **rotate** the eyelid, **duplicate with (shift+D)** for the upper eyelid.

[image]

Now you can **join** them togher with **(ctrl+j)** and **mirror** them to the other side. For the mirror object you can use the head(sphere.001)

By appling the **"visual Geometry to Mesh"** with **(ctrl+A)** you can **apply all modifiers**.

**Remesh** them with **voxel Size 0.002 or lower** and you get kinda the result your looking for.
[image]